# Hide previous and next month cells from a calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove previous and next month dates from the following calendar.

[image]

```
jQuery('.c-day').each(function() {
    let jqThis = jQuery(this);
    let date = jQuery.trim(jqThis.text());
    console.log(date);
});
```

The above jQuery code selects all cells. This is what I get.

```
30
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

However, I can filter/remove `30` from the beginning and `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` from the end but this does not work with other months like November, December, January etc?

```
jQuery('.c-day').each(function(i) {
    let jqThis = jQuery(this);
    let date = jQuery.trim(jqThis.text());
    console.log(date);
    if (i == 0 || i > 29) jqThis.hide();
});
```

Can someone please help me with the logic here?

Comment: In your picture, they look different than your current month cell. You should inspect the DOM and look if they have a class that the current month cell don't have. You can then filter onty element having those classes.

Comment: Which calendar library are you using?

Comment: Correct but unfortunately this plugin is not using classes. The CSS is hard coded with the element itself.

Comment: What is that library you are using for the Calendar?

Comment: @reachtokish It is a wordpress plugin called Amelia.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak your if statement to get what you want:

```
jQuery('.c-day').each(function(i) {
    let jqThis = jQuery(this);
    let date = jQuery.trim(jqThis.text());
    console.log(date);
    if (i == 0 || (i > 29 && date < 12)) jqThis.hide();
});
```

What this change does `(i > 29 && date < 12)` is using both the `index` and the date you already have. If the index if above 29 it means that it probably is from the next month, but we can't be sure since some months have 30 days and some 31. So we check for `date`. If the value is below 12 it means it's from the next month.

I chose 12 since I think no calendar will show more than 12 days from next month, but you can modify it if I'm wrong, a value up to 20 or something would work equally well.

---

Since December has many days from the previous month, a different logic is necessary, which should always work:

```
jQuery('.c-day').each(function(i) {
    let jqThis = jQuery(this);
    let date = jQuery.trim(jqThis.text());
    let dayCounter = 1;
    console.log(date);
    if (date > dayCounter || date < dayCounter){
      jqThis.hide();
    } else {
      dayCounter++;
    }

});
```

This works by knowing that all days from the previous month will be bigger than day 1, and all days from next month will be smaller than the last day of the month. We keep track of the day we're on, so the days of *this* month are never hidden.

Comment: I like this logic but it doesn't seem to work with the month of December. [link](https://i.ibb.co/xsFrB0b/Book-Driving-Lessons-Online-Russell-BSM.gif)

Comment: I see. Different logic is needed then. Editing

Comment: Edited. The logic should be sound, but I didn't get to test the code @AZee

Comment: Not working. Only day 1 is visible. Do you think if we create an array of days 1 to 31 and map elements from this `each loop` hiding everything until we get 1. Then after 30 or 31 every next element should also hide.

Comment: `var begins = false;
jQuery('.c-day').each(function() {
 let jqThis = jQuery(this);
 let date = jQuery.trim(jqThis.text());
 if (date == 1) begins = true;
 if (begins == false && date >= 30) {
  jqThis.hide();
 }
});` still no luck